# Parsing html text to UILabel, Text completely unreadable. Encoding issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to parse an "**Arabic text**" from an HTML page to one of my labels in my app. I'm using Ben Reeves' [HTML Parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser).

I've succeeded to parse the line, however, the line was completely unreadable. Something like this **"ÙØªØ¯ÙØ§Øª Ø§ÙÙØ§Ø¯Ø§ÙÙ Ù"**

After some checkup I think my problem is in one of these 4 lines. (I wrote them to download the page content)

```
NSString *googleString = @"http://x1q.com/alf_news_app.html";
NSURL *googleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleString];
NSError *errorss;
NSString *googlePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:googleURL
                                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&errorss];
```

I understand that `UILabel` show exactly what it has with no change. And I bit that I have to decode something to get the readable text. Though, I have no idea how.
Your help is appreciated.

Note: Not very experienced in Obj-C

Comment: That page was flagged as hostile when I tried to visit it, but nevertheless, have you tried different values for `encoding:`

Comment: Yes I did. But It does not parse anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page that you are downloading uses UTF-8 encoding, so instead of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

I.E. change the last line to:

```
NSString *googlePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:googleURL
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:&errorss];
```

Comment: I actually did use NSUTF8StringEncoding  But It does not parse anything.

Comment: When you say that it does not parse anything, what is the result in your string when you use the correct encoding?

Comment: I just tried that exact code, and NSLog'd googlePage and it works perfectly, Arabic text and all.

Comment: Oh! Yes it worked with the link above. I just created a clean html page. The page I'm trying to parse data from is still not working. I get an error from HTML Parses.

Comment: I have to recheck that page now, since the problem is not in the code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with Arabic.
The solution was to use `NSUTF16StringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`